# angular material disable pagination or pull right

Tags: angularjs, tabs, pagination, angular-material

I'm having trouble adjusting the pagination bar generated by the angular Material Design directive.
In the documentation it says to add md-no-pagination(boolean) inside the  which I tried but nothing happend...

You can try here, there a link to codePen.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs

Alternatively, is there a way to display the pagination on the right side? In the documentation there is only an attribute to center it...

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What version of angular-material are you loading?  I don't see docs for `md-no-pagination` in some slightly older versions (https://material.angularjs.org/0.11.4/api/directive/mdTab)

Answer (score 1):

The `md-no-pagination` property is working properly. I've modified the plunker on 1.0.5 and it's working. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoVqZN

Probably you are miss typing something or using `false` instead `true`.

```
<md-tabs md-no-pagination="true">
```

You can even use just the property, like this:

```
<md-tabs md-no-pagination>
```

`true` is default value for this property.

Comment: Hi i think maybe i did use the wrong terms, with pagination i meant the tabs showing in the header (ONE, TWO, THREE....)